# Angular 4 calling Component from Service using Observable and Subscribe

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service calling a component via Observable and Subscribe but for the life of me I can not see any results from my component. My code is as follows. The service and the Component is registered in my app.module.ts.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MyService {

  private messageSource = new Subject<any>();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  doSomething() {
   this.messageSource.next();
   console.log(" doSomething .........");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'angular-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css'],
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   private subscription: Subscription;
   message:string;

   constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.myService.currentMessage.subscribe(() => {
     alert('(Component2) Method called!');
    });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you see the `console.log(" doSomething .........");` in your console ?

Comment: To me, the thinking here is backwards. The service is not calling the component. Instead your service exposes a subject that can broadcast. Then the component subscribes to the service's subject to listen for emissions. So ultimately the component is calling & listening to the service. Where do you call `doSomething` in your component?

Comment: It's actually what he does, but I guess he didn't write it down correctly...

Comment: I call the doSomething from an HTTPInterceptor and yes i do the doSomething in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on your RxJS version, but afaik you can use `subject.next()` with no value.

To me there are two possibilities :

- Either your RxJS version is too low and the `next()` without value doesn't do anything (I don't think that's the issue here).
- Or there is an issue with the way your components are doing the communication. It could be because you call the `doSomething()` method from another component and the one that should `subscribe()` isn't loaded correctly and therefore cannot receive the result, in which case I advise you should check if your components are loaded correctly, and I'd also move the subscription from the `ngOnInit()` to the `constructor()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is putting something into your `messageSource`?

I'm used to seeing something that looks more like this:

```
  doSomething(message: string) {
   this.messageSource.next(message);
   console.log(" doSomething .........");
  }
```

This then adds the message onto the Observable stream which will then be broadcast to your subscribers.

(But even if it is not passed a value, it should still be broadcasting a notification and you should be seeing your alert.)